# ASP.NET GridView OnDataBound Sort in Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView where one of the columns/fields has checkboxes; the checkboxes are checked or unchecked, based on a sub-query from the code behind, while the container GridView is bound to a SqlDataSource. What I want to be able to do is that once the GridView is databound then make it sort by the state of checkboxes: All rows with checkboxes checked appear on the top of grid. Here is part of my GridView:

```
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="ProductSelector" runat="server" Checked='<%# ShowCheckMarks(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"prodid").ToString()) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I am thinking that I can call the GridView's Ondatabound event and someone make it sort from there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the good helpers here suggested, I needed to have main sql query to populate the GridView  to sort the records, instead of a different query in the code behind. So now the Declarative SqlDataSource syntax is the following. This solves the problem.
I learned a few hew things from the feedback here. Thank you all!

```
SELECT DISTINCT Products.prodid,
Products.itemtitle,
Products.itemnumber,
Products.image_1, 
 CASE WHEN YESNO IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END AS CheckUncheck
FROM Products
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT prodid_recommended as YESNO FROM products_recommended 
WHERE @itemid IN (prodid)  ) A 
 ON Products.prodid = A.YESNO
  ORDER BY CheckUncheck DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only row that you need to sort by why not just add an order by to the sql query you're using to pull the data?

Comment: Yes. The only row to sort. And, no, the sub-query is way too, multi table complicated for me. So I can't change that.

Comment: How are you bind your GridView? Are you using a datasource control of some sort or are you binding it in the code behind somewhere?

Comment: The main GridView is bound to a declarative SqlDataSource in the .aspx file. From there, as you can see, the checkboxes are checked or not based upon an array which gets populated with another query...

Comment: In the select statement for the sqldatasource you are selecting a few specific columns, regardless of what tables they come from. Whichever column applies to the checkboxes add to the end of the select statement in an order by. "SELECT col1, col2, col3 from tab1 join tab2 join tab3 where blah blah order by col3"

Comment: Nakor: The checkboxes are shown based upon values in another table. Please see both queries in my post to @Damien a few seconds ago. Thanks.

Comment: Nakor: Yes. That's what I want. I think my problem is that I need to come up with the main SqlDataSource query to grab any values from the products_recommended table

Comment: I have modified my SQLDataSource to grab only the Records which are presented in both Products and ProductsRecommended tables. But that's now what I want: I want to grab all from Products and any matching from ProductsRecommended in such a way that if matching are found then checkboxes are checked; if not found then checkboxes are not checked. Anyway, here is the query which only returns matching records (in the next comment)

Comment: SELECT dbo.Products.prodid, dbo.Products.itemtitle,dbo.Products.itemnumber,dbo.Products.image_1, dbo.products_recommended.recommendedid 
        FROM  dbo.Products  INNER JOIN dbo.products_recommended ON (dbo.Products.prodid = dbo.products_recommended.prodid)
                WHERE  dbo.Products.prodid IN (dbo.products_recommended.prodid) AND (dbo.Products.prodid = @itemid)

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself a lot of work if you

> store the state of checkbox in database

. That way you can easily set a sort expression on the template field.
**Edit**

> You can do this on clientside via jQuery tablesorter but it might be a
>   bit too much of work [Check this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30011/Sortable-GridView-using-jQuery-s-TableSorter).
>   Again I think you can somehow manipulate the query to achieve this.

Try this

```
SELECT dbo.Products.*, dbo.products_recommended.* FROM dbo.Products INNER JOIN dbo.products_recommended ON (dbo.Products.prodid = dbo.products_recommended.prodid) WHERE dbo.Products.prodid IN (dbo.products_recommended.prodid) AND (dbo.Products.prodid = " + itemid + " order by dbo.Products.prodid desc )"
```

Please note : Never use a

```
select a.* from YourTable a
```

This will select all columns from your table & may bring a serious problem later on. Only query the columns you want like

> select a.column1,a.column2 from YourTable a

Comment: What is 'prodid' in database? Is it state of checkbox ?

Comment: prodid is the primary key: Int

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of work at client side if you somehow do it with the sql query. Can you post a little bit of your query ? Updated 1st post.

Comment: The main SQLDataSource query: SELECT * FROM Products while the second query, in the codebehind (which populates an array to feed the checkbox's function call) is:  string sqlstring = "SELECT dbo.Products.*, dbo.products_recommended.* FROM  dbo.Products  INNER JOIN dbo.products_recommended ON (dbo.Products.prodid = dbo.products_recommended.prodid) WHERE  dbo.Products.prodid IN (dbo.products_recommended.prodid) AND (dbo.Products.prodid = " + itemid + ")";

Comment: Check updated reply. Just a shot without guessing your schema & Nakor has a valid point as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dbo.Products.prodid,
dbo.Products.itemtitle,
dbo.Products.itemnumber,
dbo.Products.image_1, 
CAST(ISNULL(dbo.products_recommended.recommendedid, 0) as BIT) as recommendedid
FROM dbo.Products LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.products_recommended 
ON (dbo.Products.prodid = dbo.products_recommended.prodid) 
WHERE dbo.Products.prodid IN (dbo.products_recommended.prodid) 
AND (dbo.Products.prodid = @itemid)
```

The left outer join will make sure it pulls all items from the Products table while only pulling matching items from the products_recommended table. It will also convert the recommendedid to a BIT value which should work with the checkboxes

Comment: Hi Nakor. I think we may be getting closer: I tried your sql syntax and it does return the appropriate products but it only returns them--so the LEFT OUTER JOIN is probably not working.

Comment: Perhaps the LEFT OUTER JOIN should be: LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.products

Comment: No, not sure about LEFT OUTER JOIN. Sorry.

Comment: In this case, the LEFT OUTER JOIN and the WHERE clause are in conflict? The LOJ would have returned all Products but the WHERE clause is forcing to return only those Products whose prodiid = @itemid ?

Comment: What we probably need is some kind of IF/ELSE or CASE for a sub query if prodid = @itemid

Comment: try removing the "dbo.Products.prodid IN (dbo.products_recommended.prodid) "

Comment: Still only the limited values after removing the IN. But I think I may be getting closer by trying an IF/ELSE clause..

Comment: Nakor: Here is a link to a file which has my IF/ELSE in it. It does return all products but returns all Products whether or not they have the entry in the products_recommended table or not--which is expected. However, currently it shows checked status for all Products instead of the argument prodid: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c0L5GHE9C2ZPboq26uv9k97wx2-1SBPu9RZmZR3ztMY/edit

Comment: is the checkbox for the product prodid or the recommended.prodid?

Comment: In plain English: Select all Products from [Products] table. If @prodid argument is found in [Products_Recommended] table's 'prodid' field then grab the corresponding 'prodid_recommended' field from that row and show a checkbox as checked for in the main Products query.

Comment: Ahh!Got the query to work! Using a sub-query. Check out that Google document from my two posts above. I will post an Answer later. Thank you for your help!